# How to achieve applying effects to video in iPhone using COCOS2d or Galaxy engine frameworks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to use cocos2d or galaxy engine framework. Is there any possibility for applying effects
to video that changing color video to Black and White and applying vintage effects etc?

If there is possibility to do that, How can we do that?
please help me in this regard.

Thanking You

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Galaxy, but I *can* tell you that Cocos2D is NOT what you are looking for.  Cocos2D is a 2D graphics framework based on OpenGL.  AFAIK it does not have any support for handling videos.